# How to open a project.json dotnet project in VS Studio

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have a dotnet core project that I have created using the project.json and VS Code. So there are no .sln or .xproj files.

How do I open this project in VS Studio 2015?

Answer (score 5):

You can open empty VS instance, then `File -> Open -> Project/Solution` and open your project.json file. This will generate .sln file, that you can use next time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can open this project directly in VS as ASP.NET Core projects now is able to run without using VS on other platforms. If you have created the solution using Yeoman or `dotnet CLI`, you have to create a blank new project of ASP.NET Core in VS, and drag all the working files to the solution explorer.

It is recommended that you do it once. If you try again and again, it may fail, as happened with me because IIS configuration can change each time.

*Note: If you are cloning the project, using Version Control extensions might be helpful.*